# Run elevated process

Tags: c#, process, admin-rights

I am trying to run a cmd command with the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
cmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmd.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process exec = Process.Start(cmd);
exec.StandardInput.WriteLine("sc create \"BaliService\" binPath= \"{0}\\BaliService.exe\"", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

This command requires admin privelages, if I run cmd as administrator and type the command it works perfectly but not when I run this app as admin. I have added

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

to a manifest file which prompts uac each time I open the exe.

I have seen multiple questions on this and they all seem to suggest any processes run under an elevated app will have the same rights but this isn't working for me.

I have tried `cmd.Verb = "runas";` but no dice.

Comment: Try changing `cmd.UseShellExecute` to `true` and keep the `runas` verb.

Comment: Just tried it but got this error `The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.` Thanks.

Comment: That's where the buck stops, you cannot have it both ways.  UAC prevents an unelevated process from hi-jacking the capabilities of an elevated one.  The only way you can redirect is to elevate yourself first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set `UseShellExecute` to `true` for the `Verb` to be respected and it must be set to 'false' to redirect standard output.  You can't do both.

I'm pretty sure Windows also won't allow you to redirect standard input/output/error across the admin/non-admin security boundary.  You'll have to find a different way to get output from the program running as admin.

I didn't read this article, but this may give you more information:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UAC__The_Definitive_Guide.aspx

Comment: I try using  UseShellExecute = false;  Verb = "runas"; RedirectStandardInput = true; Domain = du[0];
UserName = UserAdministrator;
Password = SecureStringHelper.ToSecureString(pwd);
LoadUserProfile = true;

And using requestedExecutionLevel in manifest.

If I use UseShellExecute = true; I get the error The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to start a process as a user.

Comment: Full sample different way to get output from the program running as admin ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try assigning administrative credentials to your `ProcessStartInfo` object?

```
SecureString password = new SecureString();
password.AppendChar('p');
password.AppendChar('w');
cmd.UserName = "admin";
cmd.Password = password;
```

Comment: I can't do this as I need UAC to prompt for them as it will be used on multiple PC's, thanks.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Can you tell me why you are creating a command process and directing it to execute "sc" rather then running the "sc" command directly ?

Comment: I am trying to run the sc command through a button on a winform as the user won't know how to use sc, just to make it easy for them to use the program.

Comment: What I am asking is why aren't you running 'sc' directly i.e. cmd.FileName = "cmd.exe" and cmd.Arguments = String.Format("create \"BaliService\" binPath= \"{0}\\BaliService.exe\"", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).

Comment: @Abbas: this solution was working for me until Win10, now the new process will not be elevated when the orignal process wasn't elevated itself. Do you have an idea for this?