# Redirection of standard and error output appending to the same log file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to collect the standard output and error log from several processes into one single log file.

So every output must **append** to this log file.

I want to call all the jobs with lines like this:

```
$p=start-process myjob.bat -redirectstandardoutput $logfile -redirecterroroutput $logfile -wait
```

Where do I have to put the information to append?

Answer (score 101):

In order to append to a file you'll need to use a slightly different approach. You can still redirect an individual process' standard error and standard output to a file, but in order to append it to a file you'll need to do one of these things:

1. Read the stdout/stderr file contents created by `Start-Process`
2. Not use Start-Process and use [the call operator, `&`](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html)
3. Not use Start-Process and start the process with .NET objects

The first way would look like this:

```
$myLog = "C:\File.log"
$stdErrLog = "C:\stderr.log"
$stdOutLog = "C:\stdout.log"
Start-Process -File myjob.bat -RedirectStandardOutput $stdOutLog -RedirectStandardError $stdErrLog -wait
Get-Content $stdErrLog, $stdOutLog | Out-File $myLog -Append
```

The second way would look like this:

```
& myjob.bat 2>&1 >> C:\MyLog.txt
```

Or this:

```
& myjob.bat 2>&1 | Out-File C:\MyLog.txt -Append
```

The third way:

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "myjob.bat"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = ""
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$output = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$output += $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
$output | Out-File $myLog -Append
```

Comment: Does it works for Powershell Remoting? I have testing, I think only the second way works for PS Remoting.

Comment: The third way causes a deadlock in some circumstances, read the MSDN or discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8762068/151641

Comment: Excellent! `2>&1 | Out-File $file -Append -Encoding UTF8` is afaik the only way to redirect both stdout and stderr *and* use UTF-8 output.

Answer (score 24):

Like Unix shells, PowerShell supports `>` redirects with most of the variations known from Unix, including `2>&1` (though weirdly, order doesn't matter - `2>&1 > file` works just like the normal `> file 2>&1`).

Like most modern Unix shells, PowerShell also has a shortcut for redirecting both standard error and standard output to the same device, though unlike other redirection shortcuts that follow pretty much the Unix convention, the capture all shortcut uses a new [sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) and is written like so: `*>`.

So your implementation might be:

```
& myjob.bat *>> $logfile
```

Answer (score 23):

Andy gave me some good pointers, but I wanted to do it in an even cleaner way. Not to mention that with the `2>&1 >>` method PowerShell complained to me about the log file being accessed by another process, i.e. both stderr and stdout trying to lock the file for access, I guess. So here's how I worked it around.

First let's generate a nice filename, but that's really just for being pedantic:

```
$name = "sync_common"
$currdate = get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd
$logfile = "c:\scripts\$name\log\$name-$currdate.txt"
```

And here's where the trick begins:

```
start-transcript -append -path $logfile

write-output "starting sync"
robocopy /mir /copyall S:\common \\10.0.0.2\common 2>&1 | Write-Output
some_other.exe /exeparams 2>&1 | Write-Output
...
write-output "ending sync"

stop-transcript
```

With `start-transcript` and `stop-transcript` you can redirect ALL output of PowerShell commands to a single file, but [it doesn't work correctly with external commands](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/315875/unable-to-capture-all-session-output-into-a-transcript). So let's just redirect all the output of those to the stdout of PS and let transcript do the rest.

In fact, I have no idea why the MS engineers say they haven't fixed this yet "due to the high cost and technical complexities involved" when it can be worked around in such a simple way.

Either way, running every single command with `start-process` is a huge clutter IMHO, but with this method, all you gotta do is append the `2>&1 | Write-Output` code to each line which runs external commands.

Comment: Because it can't, it depends precisely on what the program you called does. In this case "robocopy" works, that's not true for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not quite as elegant, but the following might also work. I suspect asynchronously this would not be a good solution.

```
$p = Start-Process myjob.bat -redirectstandardoutput $logtempfile -redirecterroroutput $logtempfile -wait
add-content $logfile (get-content $logtempfile)
```

Comment: It doesn't actually work because Powershell doesn't allow you to redirectstandardouput and redirecterroroutput to the same file. "Start-Process : This command cannot be run because "RedirectStandardOutput" and "RedirectStandardError" are same. Give different inputs and Run your command again." is the error I got when I tried this.

Comment: I think the poster meant to use $logFile for -redirectstandardoutput. The exe would write to the two files and then the second line appends one file to the other. That would work. But, it does not collate the lines; just appends. Often an exe writes to err only at the end of a run so that would often work. But not in the general case.