# Running a process using New-Object hides it

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a need to grab the stdout from an external program and bring it back into Powershell. I found and am using the answer provided by @Andy Arismendi from this question ( [Redirection of standard and error output appending to the same log-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925323/powershell-redirection-of-standard-and-error-output-appending-to-the-same-log-f)).

The snippet below works great for me, however the external executable runs silently in the background. Is there a way to prevent it from hiding?

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "myjob.bat"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$pinfo.Arguments = ""
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$output = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$output += $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
$output | Out-File $myLog -Append
```

Comment: Yes it shows up as a separate window if I invoke it via `Start-Process`. But this doesn't give me the stdout that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set `UseShellExecute` to `true`, but you cannot redirect the input and output streams, then.

Comment: That's what I had assumed, and it works fine with `Start-Process` too, but I need the stdout.