# Redirect PowerShell stdout to a file when executed in a remote session

Tags: powershell, logging, powershell-remoting

I need to log everything printed to stdout to a file. `Start-Transcript`/`Stop-Transcript` works great and does exactly this, but only for the local PowerShell sessions. The problem is that Transcripts are not supported when executing PowerShell scripts in a remote session (using `Enter-PSSession` cmd).

Is there another (preferably simple) way to redirect all output to a file, even if the .ps1 script is executed in a remote session?
I'd prefer not to have to add `>>` or `Tee` or `out-file` etc. to every line in the script that has output.

I also do not want to `Start-Transcript` before entering the remote session. I'm remoting to many destinations in a loop and I need each remote session's stdout logged to a separate file (local to the endpoint), not all bundled into a single file.

Comment: This should help you out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178319/powershell-save-stdout-and-display-stdout

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `Start-Transcript` before entering the session, and using the `-Path` option of that cmdlet to point to a separate file for each session. Perhaps something like

```
Start-Transcript -Path C:\Logs\$MachineName-$($(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm")).log
```

Or something similar. My personal preference is a date-time appendage for historical purposes.