# Is there a way to log the output of npm install command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I ran `npm install`
on a project and it gives a number of errors and warnings that I want to catch, but the output is too long and being cut off so I can't view the full list in the terminal.

I tried redirect it to a file but the output is still being written to the terminal and I still get an output file which only list the dependency trees.

I also tried to pipe it to less in linux but it still run through many screens until stopped for continue.

I checked npm doc and it doesn't seem to have log functionality, what I want is to be able to log the exact output in a file, how can I do it?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`npm install 2>&1 | tee log.txt`

The `2>&1` routes stderr to stdout, so everything will output in a single stream.

Comment: Or also do nohup and check out nohup.out

Comment: Great, learned something new. BTW use `npm install > log.txt 2>&1` instead if want to silence the terminal output.

Comment: thanks, does anyone have a quick explanation for why *npm install >> foo.log* does not work?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I suppose because the output of the command is not the same as STDERR, so you would get just a partial output when using a simple append.

Comment: @BenisonSam not sure, but I think yes; check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925323/redirection-of-standard-and-error-output-appending-to-the-same-log-file)

Comment: I found this useful with other npm commands as well. For example, I'm using jsdoc-to-markdown, and I made an npm script `"scripts" { "doc": "jsdoc2md ./app.js 2>&1 | tee jsdoc.md" }` to create a markdown document for my app.

Comment: `npm install --loglevel verbose > log.txt 2>&1` for detailed output
`npm install --loglevel silly > log.txt 2>&1` for even more detailed

Answer (score 4):

You may only be interested in the warnings and errors, if so try this:

> The npm arg is `--silent`. Or `npm config set loglevel warn` if you want to only print warnings and errors. Or you can pipe it to `/dev/null`.

so you have 2 options:

1. `npm i --silent`
2. `npm config set loglevel warn` then `npm i`

References:

[npm install should be quiet](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2040)

[Add option to hide summary output from npm install](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10732)