# Vagrant: Run a script that is visible on a windows guest

Tags: powershell, selenium, command-line, vagrant

I am provisioning a guest windows machine (both win7 and 10) with Vagrant and I want to start a process on the guest (the selenium server jar) that is visible to the guest. In other words, when the user logs into the gui I want the command window sitting there open running my jar.

How can I do this?

I've been able to start the process using vagrant's shell provisioning to run a ps1 file but it is always hidden when I log into the gui.

Here is the shell portion of my Vagrantfile:

```
win7.vm.provision "shell", path: "start_selenium.ps1", powershell_args: "-WindowStyle Normal"
```

And here is start_selenium.ps1:

```
$selenium_out = "C:\sel\selenium.jar"
$java = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre*\bin\java.exe"
Start-Process $java -ArgumentList '-jar', $selenium_out -WindowStyle normal
```

Answer (score 0):

The process runs but it does not open in PowerShell window. If you look in task explorer you will see the Java process or you can check in PowerShell `Get-Job`

You can look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925323/redirection-of-standard-and-error-output-appending-to-the-same-log-file) to redirect the output of the java command in an output so you can review when the node connects to hub etc