# Powershell executing python: redirect print statements only?

Tags: python, powershell, redirect, output

Is there a way in Powershell to redirect the print statements from python one place and the return statements to another place?

For instance i'm trying

```
$ python myPythonScript.py args >> logFile
```

I get print statement output in my log file (though it looks awful, cleaning will be the next job)

However, i do not get the return statement values from the python in the output.  Nor do i catch them if I use `*>>`

Any ideas what's happening?

Python Example:

```
def main(args)
     print "This goes to file"
     #parse flags...
     #do something here...
     MyVar = "Please " + "Work"

     return MyVar #doesn't go anywhere
if(__name__ == '__main__':
     main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What is for you a "return statement" ?

Comment: Python example added

Comment: You can only return integers from your application, so you won't be able to get that string. You use `echo %errorlevel%` to print the returned int value of your python script. I will make an answer.

Comment: `sys.stderr.write()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a program (or exit code) can only be an integer, not a string.

First, ensure you return an int, or do `exit(n)` where n is an int.

You might want to also fix:

```
if(__name__ == '__main__'):
     return main(sys.argv)
```

You can then access the return value of your program (script) in Powershell with `echo %errorlevel%`

If you really want a string to be used by powershell, you should:

1. print your logs on stderr instead of stdout
2. print the filename on stdout at end of execution
3. redirects stderr to your logfile and stdout to a powershell pipe `|` if you want a redirection - or you can execute the python script within parentheses `$()` so the result can be used on command line

Comment: Thanks Fabien.  How do I get the string I need though?  In my actual program the string I need back is a file name - an integer won't work.

Comment: I'm playing with this now.  How do I direct one to log-file and one to pipe? There's good examples  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925323/redirection-of-standard-and-error-output-appending-to-the-same-log-file),  but how do direct to two separate places on one call? `-RedirectStandardOutput` seems to only accept a file?

Comment: What you do is redirect stderr only, and stdout is naturally conveyed through a pipe. I recommend you also try the `$()` feature, it is helpful.