# How can I print the output of Rust's cargo to a text file?

Tags: powershell, logging, rust, rust-cargo

I have the following problem: I compile and run Rust program whose code I don't know too well using `cargo run`. It compiles fine, but somewhere in the code is a print/logging statement that prints way too many characters, causing the console to hang and Visual Studio code to crash. Due to the crash I can't read what is actually printed out which could help identifying the error.

Is there a way to print the output of `cargo run` to a text file?

I execute the command in Powershell, but the Powershell commands I tried (`Start-Transcription` and | `Out-File -FilePath` ...) do not capture what cargo is printing out.

`cargo run > out.txt` or `cargo run >> out.txt`also prints only a few lines that are printed to the console by `println!`, but does not record the output of logging crates such as env_logger, which I would need.

Is there a way to achieve this? (My OS is Windows)

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you, that does indeed answer the question!

Comment: I think the posted answer did answer this question? It did for me after I tried doing what you did as well and followed one answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32224971/8558585). I tried the `cargo run *> your_file.txt`