# Run PowerShell script without ps1 extension and store STDOUT and STDERR into variable(s)

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Let's execute a PS script that is stored in a file that does not have `.ps1` extension:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content path\script.txt)))
```

How can I store full STDOUT and STDERR outputs into one or two variable(s), with no output to screen?

Comment: The same way you would in most scripting languages, redirection.  Add `$var =` to the start of your line and `*>&1` to the end.

Comment: Aside, why are you using `Invoke-Command` ? either `&` or `.` or even `.Invoke()` is enough to execute a scriptblock.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I think PowerShell has a limitation that file _must_ end in `.ps1` still.

Comment: My security side is internally screaming 'malicious intent!' from reading this. Hiding the fact that something's a script, and hiding any output from it seems pretty dubious to me.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley That would apply if you were trying to invoke the path like `& 'path\to\script.txt'` but op is already reading the file as plain text and creating a new scriptblock out of it so essentially `& ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content ....))` is what I meant. Also `Invoke-Expression` is another possibility. In any case this has been answered many times before just that OP didn't care to search what's already there.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley - Where exactly I need to add `*>&1` - could you please post full line?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I do care and I read many posts, sir.

Comment: First google search for a SO answer leads me to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8938256/15339544 which has the answer you're looking for but instead of redirecting to a file you would assign to a variable

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - My script is in `txt` file and that makes my case different