# Get python version from powershell 3.0 script in windows server 2008

Tags: python, powershell

In my powershell script I am trying to get the python version in windows server 2008. This script just prints the version in console but I am not getting the value into variable.

**Code:**

```
$python = & python -V
write-host "Python Version: " + $python
```

**Expected output:**

```
Python Version: Python 2.7.8
```

**Actual output:**

```
Python 2.7.8
Python Version:
```

Any one help me out.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this with something simple like `& ping -n 1 localhost`. So I actually intalled Python to test just in case and your code does work. I had to dot source python.exe for testing but `$python = &.\python.exe -V` but the output worked fine. I'm also using PowerShell 3.0. What happens when you try `$python = & ping -n 1 localhost` and `write-host "Python Version: $python"`.FYI variable will expand inside doublequotes.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. When I use <code>$python = & ping -n 1 localhost</code> code I can get the output of <code>Python Version:  Pinging AWSRIA185.one.ads.bms.com [::1] with 32 bytes of data: Reply from ::1: time<1ms   Ping statistics for ::1:     Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss), App
roximate round trip times in milli-seconds:     Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms</code>.

Comment: If I run the code <code>$python = &.\python.exe -V</code> then I get the output of <code>& : The term '.\python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.</code>

Comment: In my example i was dot sourcing the python executable since it was not part of my path. That was not meant to be a fix or anything. It just means that in your current directory in PowerShell you dont have a `python.exe`. The ping command in `Write-Host` does work. Interesting. Also use a backtick for code in comments.

Comment: for code `$puthon = & .\python.exe -V write-host "Python Version: $python"` my output is `Python 2.7.8
Python Version:  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`python.exe -V` writes the version information to the Error output stream instead of the Success output stream. You get the observed output because the "error" message is printed before `Write-Host` is run, and the first command produces no output on the Success output stream to be assigned to `$python`, so the variable is empty when used in the `Write-Host` statement.

Change this line:

```
$python = & python -V
```

to this:

```
$python = & python -V 2>&1
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: I wonder then if the newer versions of python change this since i dont have his issue with Python 3.1.4

Comment: @Matt Possibly. I tested with Python 3.3.2.

Comment: I have a typo. My version that i tested was 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as designed. For whatever reason it is sending output to console instead of the variable. This code does work for me on PowerShell 3.0

```
$python = & python -V
write-host "Python Version: " + $python
```

You even mention in comments that similar commands work as expected like the following.

```
$python = & ping -n 1 localhost
write-host "Python Version: $python"
```

While I am not sure of the root cause you can write some code that will force capture of standard output into a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object. I took the code from another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/powershell-capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process).

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "C:\Python34\python.exe"
$pinfo.Arguments = "-V"
$pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
Write-Host "Python Version: $stdout"
```

I am not sure why a simple two liner does not work for you. What happens when you do something like this?. Again I dont have Python in my Path variable so i used the fullname of the file in my example.

```
Write-Host "Python Version: $(&"C:\Python34\python.exe" -V)"
or
Write-Host "Python Version: $(& python.exe -V)"
```

Comment: `$python = & python -V 2>&1` this line solves my problem. Thanks @Matt for the response.