# Start-Transcript not logging sub function errors

Tags: powershell

Hi all I am not able to log the errors or the content from the other function which are getting called from main function

```
cls
function one
{
   $logFile = "mypath\errorlog.log"
   Start-Transcript -path $logFile -Append | Out-Null
  try
 {
    two
 }
catch
{

}
finally
{
    Stop-Transcript
}
}

function two
{
  $arguments =  @("`"$myfile`"", "/s:`"$logPath`"")
  Start-Process -FilePath myexepath -ArgumentList $arguments -wait

 // when ever there are errors or some thing that is getting logeed in to $logPath that is not getting writing in to my Transcript
}
```

So can some one help me

Comment: I think the pb is not related to where are the transcripts instruction but to the fact you have to redirect output from the process, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/powershell-capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process
Why use start-process instead of `&myexepath` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are catching the error that is thrown by 2. Also, why are you calling Stop-Transcript inside of finally. Look at this [Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx).

```
Clear-Host
function one {
    $logFile = "mypath\errorlog.log"
    Start-Transcript -Path $logFile -Append | Out-Null
    try {
        two
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_
    }
    Stop-Transcript
}

function two {
    $arguments =  @("`"$myfile`"", "/s:`"$logPath`"")
    Start-Process -FilePath myexepath -ArgumentList $arguments -wait

    # when ever there are errors or some thing that is getting logeed in to $logPath that is not getting writing in to my Transcript
}
```