# Capture output or exit status from Start-Process inside Invoke-Command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I capture the result and/or output of the executable run inside the `Start-Process` portion of this `Invoke-Command`?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SvrName -ScriptBlock {
    Param ($arg1, $arg2)
    $process = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath $arg1 -ArgumentList $arg2;
    $process.WaitForExit();
} -ArgumentList $exePath, $command
```

I want the rest of the script to stop execution if the executable invoked by `Start-Process` returns an error.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/powershell-capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process