# How to capture windows command result from Start-Process?

Tags: powershell

`$features = Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "Get-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online"
$features`

How can I get the result back into my `$feature` variable?

Comment: Run the command `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online` from an elevated window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing standard out and error with Start-Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process)

Comment: Following that link, you'd need to specify `StartInfo.Verb = "runas"` to run the process elevated.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It is an auto script which will be executed by AWS CodeDeploy. I have no control of the machine.

Comment: @BaconBits Tried the solutions in that post before, seems not working for me. This is a windows command not an external process

Comment: The point is that you must start the process elevated to begin with. You can't elevate from an unelevated process without provoking the UAC prompt. This is by design.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart What makes you think he cares about the UAC prompt?

Comment: I added the part about the UAC prompt because it gets asked about repeatedly in these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick & dirty workaround: you can use temporary clixml file to store results of Get-WindowsOptionalFeature cmdlet:

```
$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
try
{
    Start-Process powershell -Wait -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-Command Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Export-Clixml -Path $tempFile"

    $features = Import-Clixml -Path $tempFile

    # Use $features
}
finally
{
    if (Test-Path $tempFile)
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $tempFile -Force -ErrorAction Ignore
    }
}
```