# Powershell: No output to console when running Start-Process in an Invoke-Command scriptblock

Tags: powershell, teamcity, nservicebus, invoke-command, start-process

I have the following (part of a) script, which is executed from TeamCity.

```
try
{
    $result = Invoke-Command -Session $session –ScriptBlock {
        Param
        (
            [String]                            
            $serviceName
        )                       
        Start-Process "C:\<some_path>\$serviceName\NServiceBus.Host.exe" "/install /serviceName:$serviceName /displayName:$serviceName" -NoNewWindow -Wait
        } -ArgumentList $service                
    }
    catch
    {
        $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message                    
        Write-Error "ERROR: NServiceBus.Host service installation failed with exception '$errorMessage'"
    }
```

The problem is that no output is being written to the console, and thus, TeamCity will pass the build step regardless of whether or not the script block of the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet succeded.

When I run the `Start-Process` cmdlet locally on one of the target servers, I get the following output (which is what I would expect be returned when invoking the cmdlet using `Invoke-Command`):

> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. Installing service
>   ... Service  has been successfully
>   installed. Creating EventLog source  in log
>   Application...
>
> The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is
>   beginning.
>
> The Commit phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.

One workaround is to use the `-Redirectxx <some_log_file>` switch on `Start-Process`, read the log file and act upon whatever its contents may be. However,  I would really like to avoid this if it is possible.

I am using Powershell version 5.

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Jelphy: I added the expected output to the post - see above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Start-Process -PassThru` parameter

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-5.1

`-PassThru` :
Returns a process object for each process that the cmdlet started. By default, `Start-Process` does not generate any output.

Comment: The `PassThru` parameter only gets me a process object, it does not get me any output - as you state above. Of course, I could use the process object to get the output using e.g. the approach mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes I did not detail how to get output from the cmdlet but only the prerequisite to retrieve "any" informations from `Start-Process` because as indicated in M$ docs, `Start-Process` does not generate output without `Passthru`

Comment: OK. I tried running the script proposed by Rainer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process. However, I am still unable to get any output. Only difference between that solution and my code, is that I am running it inside of an `Invoke-Command` cmdlet. Thus, I guess the problem here is that whatever output produced by `NServiceBus.Host.exe` need to be passed to the `Start-Process` cmdlet (seemingly not happening), and in turn `Invoke-Command` should take care of "piping" any output from the former to the console.

Comment: @nils1k If you go on the machine itself does Rainer's code get you what you need in  `$p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: @Sambardo: Yes, running Rainer's code locally on the server works, i.e. all output is printed to the console. If I try to wrap the code inside a scriptblock using the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet, however, I get no output at all when running it locally on the server (`ComputerName` parameter set to localhost).

Comment: @nils1k, that's odd. I put that code into a scriptblock and tried it on both the localhost and a connected server and it worked fine. Have you tried his code as written (with ping) or only with your own exe?

Comment: @Sambardo: Sorry, I should have been more precise in my comment. My attempts were all using `NServiceBus.Host.exe`. I also tried using just the `ping.exe` command, and that works as it should, i.e. according to what you describe.

Comment: Sounds like its an issue with the difference between how `NServiceBus.Host.exe` and `ping.exe` do their output.