# powershell start-process with -RedirectStandardOutput hang the powershell console

Tags: c#, powershell, console

I have a test.exe written by c#, the code is simply call Console.ReadLine();
and I want to run:

```
$p = Start-Process test.exe -RedirectStandardOutput .\out.txt -PassThru
```

when run without -RedirectStandardOutput:

```
$p = Start-Process test.exe -PassThru
```

everything looks good.

but if:

```
$p = Start-Process test.exe -RedirectStandardOutput .\out.txt  -PassThru
```

the powershell console hang, you cannot input anything, until you close the test.exe command prompt.

why this happen, anyway can keep test.exe running and I still can use the powershell console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing standard out and error with Start-Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process)

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your problem.  What version of powershell are you using?  The only reason the console should "hang" is if you're using the `-Wait` parameter.  Also, are you using the actual console or the ISE / other dev tool?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, after running
 $p = Start-Process test.exe -RedirectStandardOutput .\out.txt  -PassThru

are you able to input anything, like $p to print out the process information?

I am using the the pure powershell console, not ISE or other stuff.

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145
PSEdition                      Desktop