# Using GitHub Actions, how do you store flake8 exit code as a variable instead of failing the workflow?

Tags: python, github-actions, flake8

I have a GitHub Action workflow file that is doing multiple linting checks. `flake8` is the first linting check and if it fails the entire workflow fails meaning the subsequent linting checks are    name: lint

```
on:
  push:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@main
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
    - name: python
      uses: actions/setup-python@main
      with:
        # pulls latest version of python, alternatively specify exact version (i.e. 3.8 -> no quotes)
        python-version: '3.9'
    - name: install
      run: |
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # fail if there are any flake8 errors
        flake8 . --count --max-complexity=15 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    ## subsequent linting jobs
```

Comment: See the [continue-on-error](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) option

Comment: @Matteo this would work great. Is it possible to have a job output variable indicating that it failed that can be used by subsequent jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [continue-on-error](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) in conjunction with the [outcome](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#steps-context) of the step. From the doc:

> steps.<step_id>.outcome   string  The result of a completed step before
> continue-on-error is applied. Possible values are success, failure,
> cancelled, or skipped. When a continue-on-error step fails, the
> outcome is failure, but the final conclusion is success.

As example:

```
  - name: Lint with flake8
    id: flake8
    continue-on-error: true
    run: |
      # fail if there are any flake8 errors
      flake8 . --count --max-complexity=15 --max-line-length=127 --statistics

  - name: Check if 'Lint with flake8' step failed
    if: steps.flake8.outcome != 'success'
    run: |
      echo "flake8 fails"
      exit 1
```