# Running GitHub Actions unders specific, existing Windows user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, certificate, github-actions-runners

I am trying to run a GHA workflow in a GitHub-hosted runner for Windows (`windows-latest`) **under a specific, already existing Windows user** instead of the default `C:\Users\runneradmin`.

Options involving [`net user` or `runas`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904273/can-i-specify-a-user-account-for-a-github-action-step-on-a-windows-runner) apparently attempt to create a new, local user in the runner. I need to add to the runner an already existing AD user, but I'm a little lost going looking at the [ActiveDirectory module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

For context, I need to run the workflow as a particular user (from a particular domain) because the flow uses digital certificates (and a cert manager called RedTrust) that are assigned to this particular user. Up until now I have been running my GHA workflow under a self-hosted Windows machine (AWS EC2 instance) where the user already exists, but I am now tasked with doing the same in a GitHub-hosted runner.

I've tried asking the IT department but they seem confused as to what I'm asking so before I ask them again, or keep trying various powershell commands, I'm hoping to get a broader idea of whether what I'm asking makes sense at all.