# pwsh: How to use `Start-Process -Passthru` AND redirect both stdout and stderr to the same file?

Tags: .net, powershell, process, stream, io-redirection

i'm banging my head against the evergreen problem of stdout and stderr redirection.

##### Small introduction

In powershell, you can do `$p = Start-Process -Passthru -NoNewWindow ...` to start a windowless process and get a `Process` object reference in `$p`.

There are also a couple of arguments, `-RedirectStandardOutput <path>` and `-RedirectStandardError <path>` that effectively redirect **the process'** stdout/stderr to the files with the given `<path>`s.

So, let's consider a simple program invocation, runnable both in `cmd.exe` and `pwsh.exe`, that generates both stdout and stderr: `cmd /c "(ver & echo errrrr >&2)"`.

I want to get a reference to the process, so i do:

```
$p = Start-Process -PassThru -NoNewWindow cmd -ArgumentList '/c','(ver & echo errrrr >&2)' -RedirectStandardOutput 'c:\tmp\ver.txt' -RedirectStandardError 'c:\tmp\vererr.txt'
```

which is the same as running

```
& cmd /c '(ver & echo errrrr >&2)' >c:\tmp\ver.txt 2>c:\tmp\vererr.txt
```

**BUT** `start-process` gets me a `Process` object that i can store in `$p`!

In any case both of these create `ver.txt` and `vererr.txt` with the corresponding streams' data (`ver`=stdout, `vererr`=stderr).

##### Question

My question is: **how can i merge the program's entire output, then redirect it to a file, **AND** get a `Process` object reference?**

By "merge the entire output" i mean as when using `>file 2>&1`:

```
cmd /c "(ver & echo errrrr >&2)" >c:\tmp\ver.txt 2>&1
```

This creates **only** the `ver.txt` file with the invocation's full output.

The simple solution of specifying the same file with `start-process`, yields an error:

```
PS > $p = start-process -PassThru cmd -ArgumentList '/c','(ver & echo errrrr >&2)' -RedirectStandardOutput 'c:\tmp\ver.txt' -RedirectStandardError 'c:\tmp\ver.txt'
start-process : This command cannot be run because "RedirectStandardOutput" and "RedirectStandardError" are same. Give different inputs and Run your command again.
At line:1 char:6
+ $p = start-process -PassThru cmd -ArgumentList '/c','(ver & echo errr …
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Is this even possible in powershell? [Handmade solutions like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761888/capturing-standard-out-and-error-with-start-process/) have deadlock and output order problems, meaning stdout and stderr data may appear NOT in order when outputting both of the streams to the same file: this might even be a .NET problem because even in pure C# i haven't found a reliable way to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

You **need to merge the output streams *at the source***, which **requires use of a *shell command* and the *shell*'s redirection features**.

Since your command already calls a shell, `cmd.exe`, simply use *its* redirection features in ore- which then obviates the need for using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process)' `-RedirectStandardOut` / `-RedirectStandardErr` parameters:

```bash
# Make cmd /c merge stderr into stdout and capture the 
# combined output in c:\tmp\combined.txt
$p = Start-Process -PassThru -NoNewWindow -FilePath cmd -ArgumentList @(
       '/c',
       '(ver & echo errrrr >&2) > c:\tmp\combined.txt 2>&1'
     )
```

The alternative is to *only* use `2>&1` as part of the shell command - which merges stderr into stdout and therefore emits *all* output via stdout - and combine that with `-RedirectStandardOut`:

```bash
# Make cmd /c merge stderr into stdout and capture the 
# combined output in c:\tmp\combined.txt
$p = Start-Process -PassThru -NoNewWindow `
       -RedirectStandardOut c:\tmp\combined.txt -FilePath cmd -ArgumentList @(
         '/c',
         '(ver & echo errrrr >&2) 2>&1'
       )
```

Note that the character encoding of the output file is determined by the console's code page, as reflected in the output from `chcp`, which defaults to the system's active legacy OEM code page.

If you want UTF-8 output, switching to UTF-8 (code page `65001`) must be done *before* making the `cmd` call, as follows - you may want to save and restore the previous values:

```bash
# Must be called *before* Start-Process
[Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375).

---

**Use with *non*-shell commands:**

If your command isn't a shell command, **you must choose which shell to call via**, and there are two basic choices; however, note that **whatever  shell you choose, *you need to be familiar with its specific syntax requirements***.

- `cmd.exe` (as used above):

  - Pass the target command to `cmd /c`
  - Append `2>&1` in order to merge stderr into stdout
  - Either *precede* that with `> yourOutputFile.txt`, or use `-RedirectStandardOutput yourOutputFile.txt`, as shown above.
  - *Quoting considerations*:

    - `"` chars. that are part of the target command generally do *not* require escaping, though if the command has *embedded*, `\"`-escaped characters, you situationally need to use `^`-quoting for `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` that happen to be present between embedded `\"...\"` sequences.
- `powershell.exe` (or `pwsh.exe`, if [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is installed):

  - Pass the target command to `powershell -Command`

    - Also specifying `-NoProfile`, i.e. `powershell -NoProfile -Command` is preferable for reasons of performance and execution-environment predictability, unless you truly need PowerShell's profiles to be loaded in order for the command to succeed (such as due to `$env:PATH` additions performed by a profile).
  - Append `*>&1 | ForEach-Object ToString` in order to merge all streams into stdout and combine that with `-RedirectStandardOutput yourOutputFile.txt`, or use `*> yourOutputFile.txt` directly, but note that the output file's *character encoding* will differ:

    - In the former case, the character encoding implied by the console's active code page is used.
    - In the latter case, it is in effect the default encoding of PowerShell's [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File) cmdlet that applies (for which `>` is, in effect, an alias), which is UTF-16LE ("Unicode") in *Windows PowerShell* and BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.
  - *Quoting considerations*:

    - Use `\"` in order to escape `"` chars. that are part of the target command.

Note:

- `cmd.exe` has the advantage of starting up noticeably more quickly than a PowerShell CLI.
- Also, `cmd.exe`'s quoting requirements are simpler.

---

A **concrete example**:

The following uses `cmd.exe`:

- to execute `php -r "fwrite(STDOUT,'out'); fwrite(STDERR,'err');"`
- saving the combined stdout + stderr output to `out.txt`

Since `'...'` quoting is used on the PowerShell side, the `'` characters embedded in the PHP command must be escaped as `''`

```bash
$p = Start-Process -PassThru -NoNewWindow -FilePath cmd -ArgumentList @(
       '/c',
       'php -r "fwrite(STDOUT,''out''); fwrite(STDERR,''err'');" > out.txt 2>&1'
     )
```

Comment: hi mr Klement once again, thanks for the reply. I was actually just using `cmd` as an example to have both stdout and stderr. but i guess the same principle applies for anything? for example, let's say i have to run `php -r "fwrite(STDOUT,'out'); fwrite(STDERR,'err');"` (i guess it should be easy to understand what it does). do i still have to use `cmd.exe` as proxy? That's would be pretty unpractical since it requires escaping (with cmd's pretty _ugly_ rules..) and whatnot. Also, it requires an external invocation, so the `Process` object represents `cmd`, not `php`, am i right?

Comment: @aetonsi, please see my update, which also shows how to execute your `php` sample command. Yes, you do need _a shell_ as an intermediary, and while it could be PowerShell too, using `cmd.exe` is ultimately syntactically simpler and also faster.